# Finding nth derivative of $\frac{1}{x^4+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, partial-fractions

I am supposed to find the nth order derivative of:
$$\frac{1}{x^4+4}$$

I tried to resolve into *partial fractions*. But it didn't work out for me.

**Edit- where I am stuck**
$$\frac{1}{x^4+4}=\frac{1}{(x-1+i)(x-1-i)(x+1+i)(x+1-i)}= \frac{A}{(x-1+i)} + \frac{B}{(x-1-i)} + \frac{C}{(x+1+i)} + \frac{D}{(x+1-i)} $$
where A,B,C,D are to to be found.
I am unable to proceed further.
If I am able to find these values, the rest is easy to handle.

I am a beginner in this subject. Please help.

Comment: Do you need the whole derivative or just the derivative at a particular point?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Kindly elaborate your apprach as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: @NinadMunshi The general nth derivative

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth+derivative+of+1%2F%28x%5E4%2B4%29) can help sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

As the roots of $p(x)=x^4+4$ are $\xi_k = \sqrt 2 e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4} + k \frac{\pi}{2})}$ where $k \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ you can write

$$\frac{1}{x^4+4} = \sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{a_k}{x-\xi_k}$$

where you have to find the $a_k$ using [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#:%7E:text=In%20algebra%2C%20the%20partial%20fraction,or%20several%20fractions%20with%20a). Based on the formula $a_k = \frac{1}{p^\prime(\xi_k)} = \frac{1}{4\xi_k^3}$, you get

$$\frac{1}{x^4+4} = \frac{1}{16}\sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{\xi_k}{x-\xi_k}$$
Then the $n$th-derivative of $\frac{a_k}{x-\xi_k}$ is easy to find. And you're done.

Comment: Please have a look, I have added where I am actually stuck.

Comment: You should look in detail at [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#:%7E:text=In%20algebra%2C%20the%20partial%20fraction,or%20several%20fractions%20with%20a) wikipedia entry that I referenced in my answer. You need to compute $a_k$ and $a_k = \frac{1}{p^\prime(\xi_k)} = \frac{1}{4\xi_k^3}$. For example, what you name $A$ in your question is $\frac{1}{p^\prime(1-i)} = \frac{1}{4(1-i)^3}$ and so on for the other coefficients.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac{1}{x^4+4}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x^4+4)^{k+1}} B_{n,k}\bigl(4x^3,12x^2,24x,24,0,\dotsc,0\bigr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x^4+4)^{k+1}} x^{4k-n} B_{n,k}\bigl(\langle4\rangle_1, \langle4\rangle_2, \langle4\rangle_3, \langle4\rangle_4, \langle4\rangle_5,\dotsc,\langle4\rangle_{n-k+1}\bigr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x^4+4)^{k+1}} x^{4k-n} (-1)^k\frac{n!}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\binom{4\ell}{n}\\
&=\frac{n!}{x^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^{4k}}{(x^4+4)^{k+1}} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\binom{4\ell}{n},
\end{align*}
where we used the formula
\begin{equation}\label{binom-bell-factorial}
B_{n,k}(\langle\alpha\rangle_1, \langle\alpha\rangle_2, \dotsc,\langle\alpha\rangle_{n-k+1})
=(-1)^k\frac{n!}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\binom{\alpha\ell}{n}.
\end{equation}

A Reference

1. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.